# Cracked Carbon Seat Tube

Tags: carbon, seattube

I was riding when my seat tube cracked as I rode over a hump.

Are there any possible fixes for this like epoxy, sanding, or something?

I'm losing sleep over this.[image: Outside Crack]

[image: Inside Crack]

Comment: Is it possible to use a ruler or measure to show how far down the tube the inside maybe-delamination is compared to the cracking on the outside?  Since there are no openings into the seat tube, it almost looks like a separate element glued into the top tube?  What's the make?

Comment: Where is the clamp that holds the seatpost in the frame ? I guess it slips over the top and was removed for photo?

Comment: can you show us the seatpost and about how far it was into the frame ?  I guess the frame is too small for you and you've tried to adapt it by extending the seatpost  above the "minimum insert" line.

Comment: _Can_ you fix it at home with some epoxy and sanding and something? Sure you can! Will it be a sufficient fix to actually hold up to future use? Well... probably not. If you had the knowledge & skills to do the job properly, you'd know it and wouldn't be asking here. Since you're asking here, odds are _really_ good that you don't have the proper knowledge and skills to do a good DIY job of it.

Answer (score 13):

This is definitely a job for a carbon repair expert, not something you can fix at home with some epoxy and sand paper. It also looks like there is a crack propagating lengthwise through the top tube?

Is your seatpost the correct diameter and a snug fit with enough length inside the frame? I’m surprised the seattube broke like that.

Comment: I wonder how much seat post was in the frame

Comment: The crack on the top tube and the gusset-shaped failure where the tubes join suggest that repair is probably infeasible.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd: I’m absolutely no expert but maybe sanding it down and putting a few layers of carbon cloth over it would be enough. The hardest part would probably be to make it fit to that complex shape without wrinkles.

Comment: @Michael could possibly be done by winding on fibre or roving but that would require a high level of skill and would be correspondingly expensive. It would be interesting if somebody had a good enough grip of engineering software to model the failure with a view to determining the precise cause: my guess would be that the bottom of the seatpost stopped half way down the top tube rather than extending beyond it, which might or might not be "insufficiently inserted", putting an enormous amount of leverage on that gusset.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Bicycle Stack Exchange.
I successfully repaired the seat tube of a carbon fiber Specialized Stumpjumper that was actually flawed from the factory yet still made it into market. As I purchased the frame set from the official Specialized eBay site and documented the flaw from the outset, when the area did prove to delaminate after a few months of use, I received a new S-works frame set as replacement.  They let me keep the damaged frame and I decided to repair it with a home repair kit from Predator Cycling.

As others have noted, there may be some more damage into your top tube and there is concern about the proximity of the seat tube crack to where the top tube joins it. These are complicating concerns and need to be evaluated before deciding whether it's feasible and safe to repair.  At home, one can somewhat evaluate the extent of damage by ["tap testing"](https://carbonbikerepair.com.au/articles/82-the-limitations-of-tap-testing#:%7E:text=How%20does%20the%20tap%20test,as%20this%20may%20create%20damage) the areas surrounding the suspected cracks. The issue there is that it's a fairly subjective test where experience with carbon fiber and carbon fiber damage can benefit the validity of the findings. Also, while a positive finding is fairly accurate that damage (delamination) is present, a negative finding does not necessarily mean there is no damage present.

That being said, I can verify that one can DIY repair many areas of a bike frame that suffered significant carbon damage by correctly utilizing the advice of experts and home repair kits offered for sale.

In my case, the seat tube developed a nearly complete circumferential crack with delamination originating from a flaw in the CF layup. The area was approximately middle of the tube and about 15mm above where the seat post insertion terminated. I was able to use three CF layers, each full circumference, each layer laid with weave direction turned 45° to previous layer and increasing in longitudinal area covered. Lots of finish sanding of the dry epoxy prior to painting with high quality rattle can products (primer plus two different finish colors to get a fair match to the dark metallic flake of the factory finish).

After almost a year of moderately aggressive single track with up to 3 foot drops to flat, 3 to 5 times a week spring thru fall, the repair area appears sound. I keep a close eye on it and I'm always listening to my bikes.  I'm completely satisfied with the result.  Followed the advice of experts and the directions accompanying the kit to the letter. It took time and planning and nearly 4 weeks from start to finish (that's time from when I first wrapped the non repair area and started sanding to when the paint was dry and I took the wrap off.  NOT included is the time to remove components and complete the full build back up, nor the study time and correspondence related to CF repair.

The following pictures are in chronological order. The first is the brand new frame and the area I noticed that eventually failed.  When I got into the repair, it was obvious the factory had noticed the flaw and actually used some sort of "bondo" prior to finish painting to cover the flaw in the lay up. Note the light color above the hole in pic 4. That's the factory bondo not CF. In pic 5, the factory bondo is more prominent above the dark color of my CF compatible body filler epoxy.

During repair, where I laid the 3 new CF layers over the cured body filler (result of this step shown in pic 7), a seat post was installed for support and to make sure the lumen of the seat tube remained consistent. Because the repair area is supported by the seat post internally, that may be a key to the success of the repair. Although, that fact didn't prevent the initial damage resulting from the flaw.

[image: New frame with a flaw]
[image: Damage appears after two months use]
[image: CF damage]
[image: after sanding]
[image: filler prior to repair]
[image: CF TEMPLATES]
[image: after layup]
[image: painted]

Answer (score 1):

I would, like probably a lot of people, recommend finding someone who's competent in carbon repair. This might mean shipping the frame somewhere, and I understand that adds time and cost. That said, carbon is quite repairable.

However, that does not necessarily mean a consumer can repair it. If you got a crack in a steel frame, but you could rent a welding torch and the associated equipment, plus watch a YouTube video - would you be confident replacing a tube?

You can buy carbon repair kits from people like Predator Cycling (which has a YouTube channel). Reputable kits should come with some good quality carbon fiber, some sandpaper of appropriate grit, high-quality epoxy, probably alcohol wipes, and whatever else is necessary. You'd sand down the area around the crack, then put a few layers of the provided carbon sheets on the crack, coating them in epoxy as you go. Then you need to compress the structure and let it cure.

Experienced carbon repairers would, as they sand through the damaged area, probably be able to determine how the carbon was laid up. That is, you would often have unidirectional sheets layered over each other, probably with the fibers running at 45 degrees or some angle. (NB: Predator's kid has woven CF, which isn't unidirectional.) Ideally, you'd want to match the original layup. As a consumer, you might not be able to determine how the carbon was laid up. You won't have the ultrasonic equipment to detect how far the crack *actually* extends, so you'd be dependent on just sanding the cracked area and seeing if the crack propagates further. There are probably other things that could go wrong that I can't even name, because I've never done this - if you have to ask on Stack Exchange, you also have never done this.

It is possible that you could repair the damage with one of those consumer kits, but it is also possible that the repair could fail later and someone else will have to sand through those added layers and undo the repair. Basically, I can't see a reason to DIY this, and I would find someone who has actually experience repairing carbon structures, which are complex. Remember, steel frames are simpler in that it's a tube welded (or otherwise joined) to another tube - would you trust a YouTube video to help you replace a tube?

Comment: It's a weirdly shaped place to try to add reinforcement on the outside, and adding layers to the _inside_ would likely prevent a seatpost of the original diameter from fitting in the future.

Answer (score 0):

[image: 3 point bending]

The free length between frame and seat could bend the tube (as sudden impact force is reacted at the seat and the road hump causing bending). We assume any small tube/rod interference during assembly did not introduce significant hoop stress.

The crack as seen is almost circumferential. If jolted ride at a hump made the crack, the fiber direction in the carbon is probably not favorable to carry shear and bending stress. (Weak joint, a strong side hammering may even knock out entire outer mating carbon tube end portion).

The tube appears not too thin, so recommended to review the composite design. For quantitative calculations carbon tube diameter, thickness and length and actual material used are required.

Tube thickness to tube diameter & diameter to tube unsupported length should be above safe ratios to avoid buckling and bending The joint may need strengthening for lateral shear resistance in the following way.

6K, 2 x 2 Twill Weave Carbon Fiber Fabric approx 1000 Mpa tensile strength as standard carbon cloth of repair kits could suffice (with standard handyman's repair procedures) although asking the manufacturer's recommendation is reassuring.

On the outside of frame tube fillet deposit three layers of epoxy wetted same carbon cloth ( cut at plus minus 45 degrees ) 40 mm width around fillet made outside. Allow to set at room temperature. An ordinary  cloth can be tied  tightly around to exert radial pressure during cure, to be removed after cure.

Information to the manufacturers as the loading at hump that cracked the tube is not too heavy.

Comment: You do also need to sand the affected area down, plus at minimum clean the surface with alcohol. I don't know what grades of carbon and epoxy would suffice, although there appear to be some people who sell kits. Basically, it is *possible* to repair this yourself, although you do take risk on because you won't have adequate information.

Comment: *Deposit three layers of epoxy wetted same carbon cloth...*  Inside the seat tube?  That can't work as the inside diameter of the tube must remain constant or the seat post won't fit.

Comment: I’d encourage you to edit your answer to add that info.

Comment: Thanks, edited it sir.